# Why does my Firebug show an error when I log into the family of Stack Overflow sites

Tags: support, stack-overflow

This is the error that is being constantly shown in my [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) console -

```
illegal character
http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
Line 1
```

When I turn off the `Show JavaScript Errors` from the Firebug console option, it does not report any error.

Why? Is there something wrong with my plugin, or is it really an error?

Comment: What OS? (I no errors here Win7/x64 latest FF & Firebug)

Comment: @Richard: My OS is Windows 7 64 bit version

Comment: Interesting. I thought I got something like this at work today when I browsed to a SO site through Visual Studio. I'll have to try it again tomorrow and see if it's the same problem.

Comment: Well, I forgot about this until now. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the error I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was because of Privoxy treating blocked scripts as images (`+handle-as-image` or `+block-as-image` action).